# How to access a computer from an Android phone

Tags: android, controls, wifi

If I want to access a computer and control that computer using an Android application through a [LAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_area_network) network, what is required to make something like that, do we always need to have a server application on the computer and the application is the client?

Answer (score 0):

No, the computer and Android app could both be clients and have communications relayed through a separate server.